# Django 403 error for static files on shared hosting using passenger_wsgi

Tags: python, django, static, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to get my Django app running on a shared hosting site using passenger_wsgi (following the instruction of the hosting provider).

Since the app is for the main domain I installed it using this folder layout:

```
    public_html
      django
        static
          css
          js
          images
        SMC_website
        templates
```

In settings.py I have:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/django/static/',
    '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/django/static/css',
    '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/django/static/js',
    '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/django/static/images',
    ]
```

In urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r"^$", views.index, name="Home Page"),
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                      document_root=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static'))
```

When I try out the "static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static'))" in the django manage.py shell I get a an empty list ([]). Not sure why, or if this is the cause of my problem.

The app runs, pulls data from the database, but generates a 403 error for any content accessed from the static folders (css, js, or images).

I have these folder permisisons:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 xxxxxx xxxxxx 4096 Dec 17 18:30 css
drwxr-x--- 8 xxxxxx xxxxxx 4096 Dec 17 18:30 images
drwxr-x--- 3 xxxxxx xxxxxx 4096 Dec 17 18:30 js

drwxr-xr-x  5 xxxxxx xxxxxx   4096 Dec 11 14:24 SMC_website
drwxr-xr-x  3 xxxxxx xxxxxx   4096 Dec 11 14:24 logs
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxxxx xxxxxx    689 Dec 11 14:24 manage.py
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxxxx xxxxxx   1442 Dec 17 18:08 passenger_wsgi.py
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxxxx xxxxxx 245760 Dec 11 14:24 smcDB.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x 10 xxxxxx xxxxxx   4096 Dec 11 14:31 static

the xxxxxx is the User Name and it is the same as the folder in settings.py above
```

In the Browser debugger I see the expected urls for the static content, e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://southmetrochorale.org/static/js/smc.js"></script>
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this 403 error?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first you need to specify your `STATIC_ROOT` within `settings.py`. This declares the folder where you want to serve your static-files from.

Then you do the command `python manage.py collectstatic`. This pulls all your static-files from your `STATICFILES_DIRS` and organizes them inside the folder you declared under `STATIC_ROOT` before.

This part:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                      document_root=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static'))
```

is only working within the django-testserver thing with `DEBUG=True`.

The problem you are facing is the production versus development.

For further reading I recommend [How to deploy static files in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Comment: OK - I followed your steps and collectstatic ran successfully with 619 static files copied to '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/django/static'.

When I then comment out STATIC_URL and restart the Django app I still get the very same 403 error.

The files are in the specified folder. the urls point the that folder, but I get a 403 permission error. I set the permission on /static and all its content to chmod -R 771 /static. Still no luck. same 403 error.

Comment: Ok, then maybe we need to see your uwsgi configuration. I know that the owner of `manage.py` is also the owner of your staticfiles. I am not an expert on this, but I guess you need to check the username and permissions of the user that is running the uwsgi-process. Because that might not be the same that is hiding behind `xxxxxx is the User Name`

Comment: manage.py owner is the same as static. The Django app is run via a passenger_wsgi.py script:

import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# Set up paths and environment variables
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'SMC_website.settings'

project_home = '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/django'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, project_home)

# Set script name for the PATH_INFO fix below
SCRIPT_NAME = os.getcwd()
......
......

Comment: Yes I understand. Still you need to know who is running that script! Imagine: Owner of manage.py and static is "Volker". But I log in on your computer as "Tarquinius" and fire up the uwsgi process. Then "Tarquinius" is the runner of the uwsgi-process and that might result in lack of permission for the uwsgi-process when it tries to look up static data. But yeah, I am no expert on that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem. Because the Django app is in a folder (django) in the main domain location (public_html) -> public_html/django and the static folder is at public_html/django/static I needed to use:
STATIC_URL = "django/static/"

All is well, all static files are now being served.